# sed append string to the end of matching lines

Tags: regex, macos, awk, sed

I am new to sed, I have a file which has below contents

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Sample' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Sample
  pod 'FirebaseCore', '7.8.0'
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', '7.2.2'
  pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '7.8.0'
  pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics', '7.8.0'
  pod 'FirebaseAnalytics', '7.8.0'
  pod 'FirebasePerformance', '7.8.0'
  pod 'Fluper', '2.0.0.1'
  pod 'lottie-ios', '2.5.0
  pod 'XYZ', :git => 'git@bitbucket.org:myteam/xyz.git', :commit => 'a32d154'
  pod 'ABC', :git => 'git@bitbucket.org:mytmteam/abc.git', :branch => 'debug101'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
          if config.name.include?("Release") || config.name.include?("Adhoc")
        config.build_settings['LLVM_LTO'] = 'YES_THIN'
      elsif config.name.include?("Debug")
        config.build_settings['LLVM_LTO'] = 'NO'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I want to add `, :binary => true` 
at the end of all lines starting with pod and matching the criteria pod 'anyWord', 'Any Number' & pod 'anyWord', :git => 'Anyword', :branch => 'anyWord'
To sum up the output should be

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Sample' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Sample
  pod 'FirebaseCore', '7.8.0', :binary => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', '7.2.2', :binary => true
  pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '7.8.0', :binary => true
  pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics', '7.8.0', :binary => true
  pod 'FirebaseAnalytics', '7.8.0', :binary => true
  pod 'FirebasePerformance', '7.8.0', :binary => true
  pod 'Fluper', '2.0.0.1', :binary => true
  pod 'lottie-ios', '2.5.0, :binary => true
  pod 'XYZ', :git => 'git@bitbucket.org:myteam/xyz.git', :commit => 'a32d154', :binary => true
  pod 'ABC', :git => 'git@bitbucket.org:mytmteam/abc.git', :branch => 'debug101', :binary => true
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
          if config.name.include?("Release") || config.name.include?("Adhoc")
        config.build_settings['LLVM_LTO'] = 'YES_THIN'
      elsif config.name.include?("Debug")
        config.build_settings['LLVM_LTO'] = 'NO'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Please help I am using sed on Mac terminal I initially tried the following regex `pod '[a-zA-Z_-]*', '[0-9].*'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** After working with OP, following version is working one. Which will do inplace save into Input_file itself. Will match the lines with matching pattern and add new value string to them.

`awk '/pod \047.*\047,[[:space:]]+(\047([0-9]+\.){1,}[0-9]+\047?)/ || /pod[[:space:]]+\047[[:alnum:]]+\047,[[:space:]]+:git[[:space:]]+=>[[:space:]]+\047git.*:(commit|branch)[[:space:]]+=>[[:space:]]+\047[[:alnum:]]+\047/{$0=$0 " :binary => true"} 1' file > temp && mv temp file`

***Explanation of regex:***

- `/pod \047.*\047,[[:space:]]+(\047([0-9]+\.){1,}[0-9]+\047?)` Checking if line has pod(string) followed by `'` till `'` followed by comma space(s) followed by `'` digits(1 or more occurrences) followed by `.`(this whole group's 1 or more occurrences) followed by `[0-9]+\047?` digits `'`(optional).
- `pod[[:space:]]+\047[[:alnum:]]+\047,[[:space:]]+:git[[:space:]]+=>[[:space:]]+\047git.*:(commit|branch)[[:space:]]+=>[[:space:]]+\047[[:alnum:]]+\047` explanation:

```
pod[[:space:]]+\047[[:alnum:]]+\047,    ##Matching pod followed by spaces following by ' follwed by alphanumeric(1 or more occurrences) followed by ',
[[:space:]]+:git[[:space:]]+=>          ##Followed by space(s) colon git followed by spaces here.
[[:space:]]+\047git.*:(commit|branch)   ##Matching spaces 'git till : commit or branch.
[[:space:]]+=>[[:space:]]+\047[[:alnum:]]+\047 ##Matching spaces => spaces ' alphanumeric followed by ' here.
```

---

---

You could use this simple `sed` for doing the same. This will not do inplace update to Input_file, run this command and once you are Happy with results shown on terminal then you could do inplace save with `-i` option to following command.

```
sed '/pod/s/$/ :binary => true/' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, look for string `pod` in each line and wherever its found then substitute end of line with new string to it.

In case you are more specific for your search criteria before substitution then  try following code.

`sed -E '/pod\s+'"'"'[a-zA-Z0-9]+'"'"',\s+('"'"'([0-9]+\.){1,}[0-9]+)?(:git\s+=>\s+'"'"'.*branch.*)?/s/$/ :binary => true/'  Input_file`

Comment: @nitinupadhyay, In case you want to be more specific with your conditions then try this one `sed -E '/pod\s+'"'"'[a-zA-Z0-9]+'"'"',\s+('"'"'([0-9]+\.){1,}[0-9]+)?(:git\s+=>\s+'"'"'.*branch.*)?/s/$/ :binary => true/'  file` once and  let me know if this helps you?

Comment: the above is not working, file has no change

Comment: @nitinupadhyay, it will print the output, for change into file we need to use `-i` option. let me know.

Comment: I am using `sed -i "" -E '/pod\s+'"'"'[a-zA-Z0-9]+'"'"',\s+('"'"'([0-9]+\.){1,}[0-9]+)?(:git\s+=>\s+'"'"'.*branch.*)?/s/$/ :binary => true/' TestPodfile`
The file has no effect

Comment: @nitinupadhyay, first run `sed -E '/pod\s+'"'"'[a-zA-Z0-9]+'"'"',\s+('"'"'([0-9]+\.){1,}[0-9]+)?(:git\s+=>\s+'"'"'.*branch.*)?/s/$/ :binary => true/'  Input_file` on your file if its printing it right.

Comment: no its not working try `echo   'pod 'FirebaseCore', '7.8.0'
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', '7.2.2'
  pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '7.8.0'
  pod 'FirebaseAnalytics', '7.8.0'
  binary_pod 'PaytmSignal-iOS', '12.6.0'
  pod 'XYZ', :git => 'git@bitbucket.org:myteam/xyz.git', :commit => 'a32d154'
  pod 'ABC', :git => 'git@bitbucket.org:mytmteam/abc.git', :branch => 'debug101'' | sed -E '/pod\s+'"'"'[a-zA-Z0-9]+'"'"',\s+('"'"'([0-9]+\.){1,}[0-9]+)?(:git\s+=>\s+'"'"'.*branch.*)?/s/$/ :binary => true/'`

Comment: @nitinupadhyay, you can't use echo for it, have it like your shown samples in a file and run `sed` command on it then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234640/discussion-between-nitin-upadhyay-and-ravindersingh13).